# Replace ; with blank in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(note VARCHAR (50))

INSERT @T
SELECT 'Amplifier'
UNION ALL SELECT ';'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Regulator'
```

How can I replace the semicolon (`';'`) with blank (`''`).

Expected Output:

```
Amplifier
''         --  here semicolon replace with blank
Regulator
```

Comment: I assume this concerns MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace ALL semicolons from any outputted cell you can use `REPLACE` like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(note,';','') AS [note] FROM @T
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetching from the given table, use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN note = ';' THEN '' ELSE note END AS note FROM @T;
```

[replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) would replace *all* occurrences of the character. Doesn't seem like you'd want that. This expression only replaces exact matches of the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) all your semicolons:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(note VARCHAR (50))

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT REPLACE(SourceColumn, ';', '')
FROM SourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2017 introduced the function TRANSLATE where you can specifiy a list of characters to be replaced

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('MAX(0,MIN(h-36,8))', '(,-)', '    ') -->'MAX 0 MIN h 36 8 '
```